# Utiliser data-center ou datacenter dans un rapport scientifique

Tags: terminologie, science

Comme illustre le titre de la question, j'aimerais savoir quelle est la plus juste utilisation du mot data-center dans un rapport.
 data-center ou datacenter

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spelling a word in the English language has nothing to do with the French language.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais plutôt "data center" et, à choisir entre vos deux propositions je dirais "datacenter". [Cette page](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/data_center) mentionne que l'écriture sans espace est *rare* et ne mentionne aucunement une écriture avec des traits-d'union. Cependant, en ligne, beaucoup d'articles utilisent l'orthographe "datacenter".

Par conséquent, "data center" et "datacenter" sont tous deux corrects mais "data-center" est à éviter.